# What's new in NHibernate 3.0

Tags: nhibernate

With NHibernate closing on a 3.0 release, what's really changed and new in it?

Any good resources for looking up the changes?

Answer (score 7):

Jason Dentlers book is good start for NHibernate 3

https://www.packtpub.com/nhibernate-3-0-cookbook/book

Also check this article - its the GA but its close to release:

http://www.zvolkov.com/clog/2010/12/04/whats-new-in-nhibernate-3-0-ga/

Comment: Thanks for the link. I think the nicest bullet point there is: ` (NHibernate.Logging) removes hard dependency on log4net.`

Comment: Definitely and the fully implemented Linq provider!! :)

Answer (score 2):

**[NHibernate 3 Alpha](http://www.developerfusion.com/news/84984/nhibernate-3-alpha-1-available/)** (full .NET Framework 3.5 support):

> With the 3.0.0 release, NHibernate
>   includes support for LINQ, along with
>   additional features such as:
>
> Along with a long list of bug fixes
>   and improvements, it has several new
>   features including a new strongly
>   typed criteria API called QueryOver;
>   lazy loading of columns; alias
>   delimiting in generated SQL; and
>   support for DetachedCriteria within
>   IStatelessSession. The new release
>   also brings improved support for LINQ,
>   overcoming the HQL limitations of the
>   previous provider.
>
> Upgrading users should be aware that
>   one of the fixes means that null
>   values in dictionaries are no longer
>   silently ignored, which has the
>   potential to break existing
>   application code.

Answer (score 0):

This is documented in the `changelog.txt` which is part of the distribution you can download.